# Why does the Lion appoint this person to be the new Lord Cypher?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

I've been reading the Dark Angel's parts of the Horus Heresy recently and I'm trying to understand the Lion's motives.

My understanding is that

> Caliban is rotten because of a demonic presence called the Ouroboros in the heart of the planet.

The Lion is aware of this and

> Antagonises the Knights of Lupus into war because he believes they are researching The Ouroboros and The Great Beasts

When the Emperor arrives and leaves to take part in the Great Crusade he quickly sends Luthor and Zahariel back to Caliban because

> He wants to limit the "taint" of Caliban to the world and not let the secrets they don't realise they know spread out into the expedition.

However he also appoints the

> Last Knight of Lupus

To be the new Lord Cypher because

> As a knight not from the original Order

his loyalty would be to the Lion, not Luthor or Zahariel.

However, this doens't make sense to me. Surely

> As The Lord Cypher is a member of the Knights of Lupus the man he's using to keep an eye on Luthor and Zahariel is actually the most untrustworthy of all of them?

Why does the Lion make this appointment?

Comment: Remember, that there is a popular theory (in-universe!) saying that during the Heresy Lion was playing both sides, waiting for the victor. So maybe even during the Crusade, he was already a bit curious about the possibility of using Uroboros (which has almost happened apparently)?

Comment: Thanks - I’m fairly new to DA and suddenly I have a new army I want to collect 